# I am looking for a list of all companies worldwide with their annual revenue

Tags: data, market-data

I am trying to find a list of all publicly traded companies worldwide along with their annual revenue.  I can get the list of stock symbols but is there a way to get their annual revenue without looking them up one at a time?

Comment: If you are an academic, then your university might have access to the CRSP/Compustat Merged Database: http://www.crsp.com/products/research-products/crspcompustat-merged-database.

Comment: Bloomberg API, field IS010.

Comment: Portfolio123.com provides a web-based API to access instutional quality data from S&P Express Feed (formerly Compustat). You can easily do this query for US and Canadian companies with one of its APIs. The cost is reasonable once you compare it to Bloomberg Terminal, S&P Capital IQ, FactSet, and most other research platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Thomson Reuters has that data for all listed companies worldwide and their reporting currency (but expensive).